# Print two different sheets on two different printers

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I'm trying to print different sheets (X & Y) on two different printers (PrinterX & PrinterY).

```
Dim PrinterX as string
PrinterX=activeworkbook.Worksheets("Printers").Range("B1").value
Activerprinter = PrinterX
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("X").Printout

Dim PrinterY as string
PrinterY = Activeworkbook.Worksheets("Printers").Range("B2").value
Activerprinter = PrinterY
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Y").Printout
```

==> I have the printer name in Range("B1") as "HP LaserJet Professional P1102 (Copy4) on Ne01" & Range("B2") as "HP LaserJet Professional P1102 (Copy1) on Ne02".

It prints both on PrinterX. I am trying to print X on PrinterX and Y on PrinterY.

`application.activeprinter` gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
application.activeprinter
```

must be:

```
Application.ActivePrinter
```

Furthermore, you may want to refactor your code as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim iCell As Long


    With Worksheets("Printers").Range("B1:B2") '<--| reference range with printers
        For iCell = 1 To .Count '<--|loop through it
            Application.ActivePrinter = .Cells(iCell, 1).Value '<--| set activeprinter to current cell value
            Worksheets(Array("X", "Y")(iCell - 1)).PrintOut '<--| define array with corresponding wanted sheets names and printout current one
       Next iCell
    End With
End Sub
```

or you could specify the `ActivePrinter` directly in `PrintOut()` method:

```
Sub main()
    Dim iCell As Long

    With Worksheets("Printers").Range("B1:B2") '<--| reference range with printers
        For iCell = 1 To .Count '<--|loop through it
            Worksheets(Array("X", "Y")(iCell - 1)).PrintOut ActivePrinter:=.Cells(iCell, 1).Value '<--| define array with corresponding wanted sheets names and printout current setting ActivePrinter to current cell value
       Next iCell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciated

However the loop is a better practice but the problem was that excel didn't switch the printer .. it prints both X & Y on the same first printer that I use. It should print x on printer x and then switch and print Y on printer Y.

Comment: I get error message:

Run-time error '1004'
Method 'ActivePrinter' of object '_Application' failed

Comment: Application.activeprinter line